# Log4j does not log in the right folder in my camel route

Tags: logging, apache-camel, log4j, apache-servicemix

Below is my log4j.xml placed in MyProject/src/main/resources
In which i have used FileAppender to redirect the log to `log.log`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">

   <param name="file" value="D:/SHARED/log.log"/>
   <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
   <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>
   <param name="append" value="false"/>

   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="conversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
   </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
   <level value="DEBUG"/>
   <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Below are the dependencies I added in `pom.xml` as mentioned in the below link
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my route which simply sends a file from directory to jms queue

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
            super.configure();

            from("file://E://Target//Customers")
            .transacted()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"FolderToJMS","Sending File to JMS Queue")
            .to("jmstx:queue:transaction-handler");
    }
```

I have deployed my route in service mix. With all these done, im not able to find the log file in D:/SHARED.

Is there something more I need to do...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about pax-logging which is what ServiceMix/Karaf uses. You cannot have your own log configuration, but need to configure using pax-logging.

You can find documentation about this on Karaf website

Comment: Thanks for your information. I tried Pax-logging which some inbuilt appenders for logging. I created my appender and deployed as a pax service as in blog http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2011/08/adding-custom-log-appender-to-pax-logging . But Im getting classnotfound exception on my appender. Am i doing something wrong??